# Error getting image from a JSON response based on an HTTP query

Tags: java, android, json, http

Here's my app. It gets a JSON String based on an HTTP query to Google Books and shows the list of all the found books. However, for some reason it doesn't show book covers for the books that have covers. For the books not having them it works fine.

I use an Android Emulator in Android Studio.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Loader;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Book>> {
    /** Adapter for the list of earthquakes */
    private BookAdapter mAdapter;

    TextView mEmptyStateTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button searchButton = findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText searchText = findViewById(R.id.search_text);
                QueryUtils.setSearchQuery(QueryUtils.getINIITIAL_GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL()
                        + searchText.getText());

                mAdapter = new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        new ArrayList<Book>());

                ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
                listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                mEmptyStateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
                listView.setEmptyView(mEmptyStateTextView);

                // Get a reference to the ConnectivityManager to check state of network connectivity
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                // Get details on the currently active default data network
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                // If there is a network connection, fetch data
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    // Get a reference to the LoaderManager, in order to interact with loaders.
                    LoaderManager loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

                    // Initialize the loader. Pass in the int ID 1 and pass in null for
                    // the bundle. Pass in this activity for the LoaderCallbacks parameter (which is valid
                    // because this activity implements the LoaderCallbacks interface).
                    loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, MainActivity.this);
                }
                else {
                    // Otherwise, display error
                    // First, hide loading indicator so error message will be visible
                    View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
                    loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    // Update empty state with no connection error message
                    mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No Internet connection.");
                }
            }
        });


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Book>> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        // Create a new loader for the given URL
        return new BookLoader(this, QueryUtils.getSearchQuery());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<List<Book>> loader, List<Book> books) {
        // Hide loading indicator because the data has been loaded
        ProgressBar loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Clear the adapter of previous book data
        mAdapter.clear();

        // If there is a valid list of {@link Book}s, then add them to the adapter's
        // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
        if (books != null && !books.isEmpty()) {
            mAdapter.addAll(books);
        }

        // Set empty state text to display "No books found."
        mEmptyStateTextView.setText("No books found.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<List<Book>> loader) {
        // Loader reset, so we can clear out our existing data.
        mAdapter.clear();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_indicator"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Book.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Book {

    private String mTitle;
    private String mAuthor;
    private String mReleaseDate;
    private Bitmap mBookCover;

    public Book(String title, String author, String releaseDate, Bitmap bookCover) {
        mTitle = title;
        mAuthor = author;
        mBookCover = bookCover;
        mReleaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return mAuthor;
    }

    public Bitmap getBookCover() {
        return mBookCover;
    }

    public String getReleaseYear() {
        return mReleaseDate;
    }
}
```

BookAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

    public BookAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super(context, 0, books);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null)
        {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.book_item, parent, false);
        }

        Book currentBook = getItem(position);

        TextView bookTitleView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        bookTitleView.setText(currentBook.getTitle());

        TextView bookAuthorView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_author);
        bookAuthorView.setText(currentBook.getAuthor());

        TextView bookReleaseYearView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_release_year);
        bookReleaseYearView.setText(currentBook.getReleaseYear());

        ImageView bookCoverView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.book_cover);
        bookCoverView.setImageBitmap(currentBook.getBookCover());

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

BookLoader.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import java.util.List;

public class BookLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Book>> {

    /** Query URL */
    private String mUrl;

    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link BookLoader}.
     *
     * @param context of the activity
     * @param url to load data from
     */
    public BookLoader(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        mUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }

    /**
     * This is on a background thread.
     */
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public List<Book> loadInBackground() {
        if (mUrl == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // Perform the network request, parse the response, and extract a list of earthquakes.
        List<Book> books = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(mUrl);
        return books;
    }
}
```

QueryUtils.java

```
package com.example.android.booklisting;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class QueryUtils {

    private static final String INIITIAL_GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
    private static String searchQuery;

    private QueryUtils() {
    }

    public static String getINIITIAL_GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL() {
        return INIITIAL_GOOGLE_BOOKS_URL;
    }

    public static void setSearchQuery(String searchQuery) {
        QueryUtils.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    public static String getSearchQuery() {
        return searchQuery;
    }

    /**
     * Query the Google Books dataset and return an {@link ArrayList} object to represent a list of books.
     */
    /**
     * Return a list of {@link Book} objects that has been built up from
     * parsing the given JSON response.
     */
    private static List<Book> extractBooksFromJson(String bookJSON) {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bookJSON)) {
            Log.e("nojson", "No JSON returned");
            return null;
        }

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding books to
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

        // Try to parse the JSON response string. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {

            // Create a JSONObject from the JSON response string
            JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJSON);
            Log.v("success", "JSONObject sucessfully created!");

            // Extract the JSONArray associated with the key called "items",
            // which represents a list of items (or books).
            JSONArray bookArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

            // For each book in the bookArray, create a {@link Book} object
            for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length(); i++) {

                // Get a single Book at position i within the list of books
                JSONObject currentBook = bookArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // For a given book, extract the JSONObject associated with the
                // key called "volumeInfo", which represents a list of all information
                // for that book.
                JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");

                // Extract the value for the key called "title"
                String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");

                String authorsString = "";

                //Extract the JSONArray associated with the key called "authors"
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonAuthors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                    ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();
                    StringBuilder authorsStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonAuthors.length(); j++) {
                        // Add a specific author to the "authors" list
                        // and add it to a the "authorsStringBuilder"
                        authors.add(jsonAuthors.getString(j));
                        authorsStringBuilder.append(authors.get(j) + ", \n");
                    }
                    //Remove the last 3 elements in the "authorsStringBuilder"
                    authorsStringBuilder.delete(authorsStringBuilder.length() - 3,
                            authorsStringBuilder.length() - 1);
                    //Convert StringBuilder to String
                    authorsString = authorsStringBuilder.toString();
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
                    // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
                    // with the message from the exception.
                    Log.e("QueryUtils", "No authors found", e);
                }

                // Extract the value for the key called "publishedDate"
                String releaseDate = volumeInfo.getString("publishedDate");

                //The link for a book cover
                String imageLink;
                // Get the JSONObject "readingModes" having information about
                // whether or not a given book has a cover
                JSONObject readingModes = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("readingModes");
                // Extract the value for the key called "image"
                boolean hasACover = readingModes.getBoolean("image");
                //Check if a given book has a cover
                if (hasACover)
                {
                    // If yes, then assign a link for the book
                    // to the imageLink
                    imageLink = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks")
                            .getString("thumbnail");
                    Log.v("Cover check", "Book has a cover");
                }
                else
                {
                    // If not, then assign the imageLink the default cover
                    imageLink = "https://books.google.ru/googlebooks/images/no_cover_thumb.gif";
                }

                //Get a book cover
                Bitmap bookCover = getImage(imageLink);

                // Create a new {@link Book} object with the magnitude, location, time,
                // and url from the JSON response.
                Book book = new Book(title, authorsString, releaseDate, bookCover);

                // Add the new {@link Book} to the list of books.
                books.add(book);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the book JSON results", e);
        }

        // Return the list of books
        return books;
    }

    /**
     * Get a book cover.
     */
    /**
     * Return a book cover
     */
    private static Bitmap getImage(String imageLink)
    {
        Bitmap image = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageLink);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            Log.e("getImage: ", "Image problems");
        }

        return image;
    }

    /**
     * Query the Google Books dataset and return a list of {@link Book} objects.
     */
    public static List<Book> fetchEarthquakeData(String requestUrl) {
        // Create URL object
        URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
        }

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link Book}s
        List<Book> books = extractBooksFromJson(jsonResponse);

        Log.v("QueryUtils", "fetching data");

        // Return the list of {@link book}s
        return books;
    }

    /**
     * Returns new URL object from the given string URL.
     */
    private static URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("QueryUtils: : ", "Error with creating URL", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    /**
     * Make an HTTP request to the given URL and return a String as the response.
     */
    private static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";

        // If the URL is null, then return early.
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // If the request was successful (response code 200),
            // then read the input stream and parse the response.
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e("", "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("", "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the {@link InputStream} into a String which contains the
     * whole JSON response from the server.
     */
    private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
}
```

Here's the example of what I'm talking about:
[image: Example query]

And a logcat:
[image]

ADDED: I've added a more specific exception logging. Here's the new logcat:
[image: I've added a more specific exception logging. Here's the new logcat]

Comment: The full exception log can be helpful, put `e` as the third parameter: `Log.e("getImage: ", "Image problems", e);`

Comment: Done. Now it says that I don't have an access to books.google.com traffic. How to fix it?

Comment: put `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in application tag in manifest file

Comment: @AkakiKapanadze I have fixed it. All I had to do was to add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` Your comment helped me to find out the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! @BiT4000